# How can I control the screen brightness from a flash app using AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

Is there are a way to control the screen brightness from a flash app using AS3? 
I would like to create a slider that will control the brightness of 3 screens.

Answer (score 1):

Flash Player holds no such a capability by default. However, your app is an AIR app, thus there is a way. You will need ANE (AIR Native Extension) that grants the access to the display(s) and its(their) properties.

You might find an existing one for your needs, or, if there are none, build your own: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air.html